# Cannot find module 'XX.scss' or corresponding type declarations - ts(2307)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sass

I created a `.scss` module and I'am trying to import it in a `.tsx` of a react project of mine, but it keeps bumping into the `ts(2307)` error.

Trying to import like this:

```
import styles from './Input/Input.module.scss';
```

Already tried to reinstall `Sass`, `types@Sass` and `css.modules`, to update all the project dependencies, to copy given project's `src` folder and paste over the src of a downloaded project with working `.scss` imports, to create a `declaration.d.ts` file with the module declaration, but **nothing worked out**, keeps showing the `ts(2307)` message (I'm using VScode, don't know if it has anything to do).

Someone has any idea how can I fix this?

`package.json` file contains:

```
{
  "name": "challenge",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
    "@types/jest": "^29.4.0",
    "@types/node": "^18.11.19",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.27",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.10",
    "classnames": "^2.3.2",
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.7.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.8.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "web-vitals": "^3.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.51.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.51.0",
    "eslint": "^8.33.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
    "sass": "^1.58.0",
    "typescript-plugin-css-modules": "^4.1.1"
  }
}
```

and
`tsconfig.json` contains

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```